# Solving a puzzle: Graph where each node has degree 3

Tags: discrete-mathematics, puzzle

I am trying to solve this puzzle:

Problem:
The  Park is covered by a network of hiking paths.

Goal: Find an algrithm by which you'll find (in finite time) the crossing at which the restaurant is located.

Rules:

1. The paths form a finite connected graph in which each crossing (that is, each crossing of paths) is of degree 3.
2. The crossings are indistinguishable one from another: it is not possible to know which crossing one has arrived at, to identify the paths meeting there, or to recognize whether one has been there before.
3. Strict rule against leaving markings in the park. It is not ok to mark crossings or path in any way.
4. If you enter a crossing by one path you must leave it by a different path. You have initially arrived at some node by one of its incident paths.

My questions:

For rule 1: I cannot find any graph where every node has a degree of 3. At least one node has degree 2.

2nd question: If I cannot mark the paths where I have been, what can I do to find a sufficient solution? Just go right, right right and one time left?

Comment: What's the goal, to visit every junction?

Comment: $K_4$ is the simplest graph where every node has degree 3.

Comment: If the goal is to visit every edge and to end up where you started, then you are describing an Euler Circuit. A graph $G$ has an Euler Circuit if and only if every vertex has even degree.

Comment: You can see another $3$-regular graph [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/3-regular_graph.svg/425px-3-regular_graph.svg.png).

Comment: @aschepler  I added the goal.

Comment: @ml0105 The graph obviously does not have an Euler circuit.

Comment: I assume the park is planar (no trails crossing by bridges), which might be required to find an answer. (Both $K_4$ and the example from @BrianM.Scott are planar, although that picture is drawn with intersections.)

Comment: @aschepler yes, it is planar... but does that have some advantages?

Comment: @aschepler: I suspect that it doen’t matter: about the only thing that one can use is the fact that at each junction one has a choice between going left and going right, and that’s the case even if there are bridges.

Comment: @ml0105: why must the solution be an Euler circuit?

Comment: @ml0105: There is no requirement that the path be an Euler circuit; it just has to be guaranteed to reach every vertex.

Comment: I confess this remark is a little flippant: we can never find the restaurant if rule 2 holds, since if the restaurant isn't a distinguishing feature of the junction that is our goal, how can we know when we've found that junction?

Comment: Any repeating pattern of left/right choices is not a solution, since we can construct an antagonist graph which makes that period a cycle without visiting all vertices. I suspect a sequence which contains every finite substring infinitely many times would do the trick, but I haven't been able to prove it.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion! I was having some trouble parsing out what the goal of the problem was.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? It reminds me of a talk I've given, and I'm curious if one of the people listening to it wrote the problem.

Comment: Also, a practical question: is the solution allowed to be based on a map of the park, or should it be a single sequence that works for parks of any shape and size?

Comment: @MishaLavrov yes, of any shape and size...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55221/need-an-efficient-algorithm-to-visit-all-nodes-of-a-graph-revisiting-edges-and

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a *hypothesis* to consist of the following:

- a $3$-regular graph representing a hypothetical map of the park;
- a vertex $r$ in that graph representing a hypothetical location of the restaurant;
- a vertex $s$ in that graph representing a hypothetical starting location;
- an edge incident to $s$ representing the hypothetical path by which you arrived at $s$.

There are infinitely many hypotheses, but countably many: for each natural number $n$, there are only finitely many hypotheses in which the park has $n$ vertices. So we may number the hypotheses $H_1, H_2, H_3, \dots$.

One of the hypotheses represents the true map of the park, location of the restaurant, and your starting position: call that hypothesis $H_N$. You don't know which hypothesis this is, but $N$ is some finite number.

---

Now, here is the strategy that will get you to the restaurant. For each $i=1,2,3,\dots$, you:

1. Assume hypothesis $H_i$ is true for the time being.
2. Given the steps you've taken so far, determine the location in $H_i$'s graph where you would now be, if hypothesis $H_i$ were true.
3. From that location, find directions in $H_i$'s graph that would take you to $H_i$'s restaurant location $r$.
4. Follow those directions in the actual physical park.

For the first $N-1$ iterations of this procedure (for $i=1, 2, \dots, N-1$), you're going to be following directions based on a false premise, and they're unlikely to get you to the restaurant except by chance.

On the $N^{\text{th}}$ iteration of the restaurant, you'll assume a true hypothesis: the graph you take will be the correct graph, with the restaurant and your starting location and starting direction marked correctly. Then the location you work out in step 2 will happen to be your actual location in the park, and the directions you work out in step 3 will actually take you to the restaurant.

Comment: the breaking point would be to left or right... but why do take the left or right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If each vertex has degree $3$, and you can't go back the way you came, there are only two options. We can call them "left" and "right".

Comment: exactly, but do choose left or right randomly?

Comment: sorry, I dont understand with the tokens? we are not allowed to mark trails. You violate rule 3.

Comment: We are not marking the trails. The algorithm I am giving is used beforehand to generate a sequence of directions to follow; then, you just follow that sequence of directions. We don't choose left or right randomly; on each map, we can look at that map to see how to get to the restaurant on that map, and give those directions.

Comment: how would you define a token?

Comment: The token is just a marker to represent a position and direction on a map. You can imagine drawing the map on paper and putting some coins on the paper and moving them around. If implementing this algorithm in a computer, they'd be a bunch of variables.

Comment: "Repeat until you've guided every token to the restaurant." Does not make sense to me, because I stop, when I find the restaurant, right?

Comment: To know the position of the restaurant I need to find all junctions, right?

Comment: @jester I have tried to rephrase my answer avoiding the terminology that confused you.

Comment: @MishaLavrov It might be easier to illustrate by backtracking to the starting position after each hypothesis is tested; this doesn't require any more ability than the procedure outlined here and has the possible visualization advantage that one tests each hypothesis from a 'clean slate'.

Comment: This could be a bit more "efficient" by checking at each new hypothesis $H_i$ if it predicts I would have already seen the restaurant. If so, toss out that hypothesis, skipping the walking around, and consider the next untested hypothesis.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Unfortunately, the rules don't let us turn around, and so returning to the start is also not something we can do without making some assumptions about the map.

Comment: there is a missing path, how to verify if the hypthesis is correct. You need to save left, right etc. until to the restaurnt, right? For that you need test every combination in a graph with start and endpoint and compare within one hyptohtesis. I think that you have described that in your previous answer.

Comment: What do you mean, how to verify if the hypothesis is correct? If the hypothesis is correct, it gets you to the restaurant, and then you win.

Comment: Different possible graphs, or even the same graph with a different start and endpoint, are different hypotheses.